# Why is position of my object not changing?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently developing a Unity3D based evolutionary algorithm. The simulation is two-dimensional. A single subject is being depicted as car, being a prefab, consisting of 3 sprites(2 wheels and body), and a CarScript. Each sprite has a proper collider(BoxCollider2D for body and CircleCollider2D for wheels). CarBody also has 
two WheelJoint2D. Parameters of those colliders are changed by code.

I want this car to be destroyed, if it stops moving or better - advancing. In the Game window, the car is obviously moving downhill. The problem is, that after checking for transform.position of gameobject, this value seems to be constant. It always shows the position of SpawnPoint. SpawnPoint is empty GameObject with SpawnScript, which fragment is below:

```
public GameObject carprefab; //Set from editor
public Transform[] spawnPoints; //transform of SpawnPoint, just one element. Set from editor.
private void GenerateCar(Chromosome chromosome)
{
int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range(0, spawnPoints.Length);
var instace = (GameObject)Instantiate(carprefab, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position,     spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
    instace.SendMessage("SetChromosome", chromosome);

    foreach (Transform child in instace.transform)
    { //code omitted for clarity, changes some of parameters based on chromosome.
```

Instantiated object has a CarScript:

```
 // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (frames%10 == 0)
            CheckForMoving();
        frames++;
    }
 private void CheckForMoving()
    {
        var pos = gameObject.transform.position; //this is never changing - why?


        var diff = pos - startingPosition; //difference between local position and starting position
        if (CountLength(diff) >= recordLengthYet)
        {
            Debug.Log("It is moving!");
            recordLengthYet = CountLength(diff);
            framesTillLastRecord = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("It is not moving");
            if (framesTillLastRecord > 4)
                Destroy(gameObject, 0f);
            framesTillLastRecord++;
        }
    }
```

I tried getting the position by any of the following:

```
var pos = gameObject.transform.position;
var pos = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("player");
var pos = this.transform.position;
```

The question is - what did I miss, or why this is not changing? I started learning Unity just recently, and had no previous experience with any  similiar software. I also wonder, if it is even the right way to do this.

Comment: `CountLength`? if you want to see how far two points are from each other I think you should be using `Vector3.magnitude` or `Vector3.sqrMagnitude`. Have you tried outputting the pos value after it is set (debug.log(pos) etc.) or are you relying on the debugs as above?

Comment: I did try outputting the value itself, and pos seems to be constant value, equal to position of SpawnPoint. Also, I will change the code later to reflect your advice, I was not aware of those properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Few days has passed, nobody had uploaded a proper answer, and I managed to get a workaround. As long as it is really dirty, it seems to work.

I placed a tag on child GameObject, instead of prefab, and I am geting position of this child by

```
var pos = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("player");
```

I am not sure, if this is really good answer, but I hope somebody might find it useful someday.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using rigidbodies, you should be overriding `FixedUpdate()` and not `Update()` as per Unity doco:

> *This function is called every fixed framerate frame, if the MonoBehaviour is enabled. FixedUpdate should be used instead of Update when dealing with Rigidbody. For example when adding a force to a rigidbody, you have to apply the force every fixed frame inside FixedUpdate instead of every frame inside Update.* - [Tell me more...](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.FixedUpdate.html)

Replace:

```
 // Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    if (frames%10 == 0)
        CheckForMoving();
    frames++;
}
```

With:

```
 // Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    if (frames%10 == 0)
        CheckForMoving();
    frames++;
}
```

Comment: Well, certainly a good advice as I was not aware of this,and I changed my code. However, this still does not fix my main issue, being a constant position of this.transform, while GameObject is clearly moving.